# Call class method with variable

Tags: php, oop

I have the following class:

```
class Actions_con extends Calls
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function redirect()
    {
        $this->_data['request'] = '_' . $this->url[3] . '()';
        return $this->{$this->_data['request']};
    }
}
```

In the parent class `Calls` I have the following method:

```
protected function _login(){
    echo 'login';
}
```

In my base class the property `$this->url[3]` is equal to "login". And what I want to do is to call this method by this variable name. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the solution. You just don't need to concatenate the parentheses, instead put them where you call the method, e.g.

```
public function redirect()
{
    $this->_data['request'] = '_' . $this->url[3];
    return $this->{$this->_data['request']}();
                                         //↑↑ See here
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution, but I have very next question in common - is it good to do things like this?

Comment: @ArnasPecelis If you use  variables to call a function/method, you just have to make sure the method exists.